# My tkinter code is crashing because of buttons or entry boxes

Tags: python, tkinter

Recently I have wanted to start learning tkinter but am having issues with my code. When I run it I can log in but after I login it crashes. I have no idea why this is happening and have tried a few things.
I have managed to make the text appear (rearrangement) so I am sure it is the button or the entry box.

```
import random import time import tkinter as tk

global play global boxy

run = False killme = "" scorefile = open("Scores.txt", "w") songfile = open("Songs.txt", "r") scf = scorefile sf = songfile.readlines() count
= len(sf) output = (count/4)-1 for f in range(0,count):
    sf[f] = sf[f].rstrip("\n")

x = 0 play = False found = False correct = False score = 0 song = "n/a" songs = ["1", "2" ,"3" ,"4" ,"5"] y = 0 randn = 0 point = 0

windowEA= tk.Tk()

boxy = tk.Canvas(windowEA, width = 500, height = 500) boxy.pack()    
#canvas ajustments
#-------------------------------------Login-------------------------------------

label1 = tk.Label(windowEA, text="""You need Authorisation to get into this file so, please enter your username and password to be premitet to play.""") label1.config(font=('helvetica', 12))   #tkinter canvas config boxy.create_window(250, 25, window=label1)

entry1 = tk.Entry (windowEA)    #creation of username entry box boxy.create_window(250, 100, window=entry1) entry2 = tk.Entry (windowEA)    #creation of password enrty box boxy.create_window(250, 120, window=entry2) entry2.config(show="*")

x1 = entry1.get() x2 = entry2.get() namer = x1+" "+x2

def namecheck (): #checking if the name given fits with the allowed ones
    global play
    found = False
    x1 = entry1.get()
    x2 = entry2.get()
    namer = x1+x2

    passwordfile = open("Authorisation names.txt", "r")
    if passwordfile.mode == "r" :
        f1 = passwordfile.readlines()
        for x in f1:
            check = x
            if check == namer:
                found = True
        if found == True:
            label1 = tk.Label(windowEA, text= "welcome to the game")
            boxy.create_window(250, 230, window=label1)
            output = "welcome to the game"
            play = True
            boxy.delete(all)
        else:
            label1 = tk.Label(windowEA, text= "Sorry incorect information")
            boxy.create_window(250, 230, window=label1)
            output = "Sorry incorect information"
    passwordfile.close()

button1 = tk.Button(text="Log In", command=namecheck) boxy.create_window(250, 180, window=button1)    #checking if info is good button
#-------------------------------------Login-------------------------------------
#-------------------------------------output------------------------------------ def update():
    global play
    gay = False
    if play == True:
        gay = True
    t = 0
    print("good update")
    while gay == True:
        print("good play")
        def checkguess():  
            gu1 = entry69.get()
            if gu1 == sf[rands]:
                correct = True
                point = point + 3
            else:
                gu1 = entry69.get()
                if gu1 == sf[rands]:
                    correct = True
                    point = point + 1
            if correct == True:
                print("Weldone the answer was "+sf[rands]+". You now have "+str(point)+" points")
            else:
                print("Good try the answer was "+sf[rands]+". But you still have "+str(point)+" points")

        label69 = tk.Label(windowEA, text=("""During this game you will be given the"""))
#first letter of every word from a song
#and the artists,you then have to work out what the song is called using the
#infomation, you have 2 guesses and will be told what it was after you finish.
#Have fun!(Capitals matter)(english letters only)."""))
        label69.config(font=('helvetica', 15))
        boxy.create_window(250, 230, window=label69)

        rand = random.randint(0,10)
        randn = int(rand)*2
        rands = randn + 1

        button69 = tk.Button(text="enter", command=checkguess)
        boxy.create_window(250, 180, window=button69)    #checking if info is good button
        label420 = tk.Label(windowEA, text= sf[randn])
        boxy.create_window(250, 100, window=label420)
        entry69 = tk.Entry(windowEA)    #creation of username entry box
        boxy.create_window(250, 140, window=entry69)

#        repeat = input("Do you want to play again?")
#        if repeat == "No" or repeat == "no" or repeat == "NO" or repeat == "nO":
#            gay = False
#            songfile.close()
#        save = input("Do you want to save your score? ")
#        if save != "NO" or save != "No" or save != "no" or save != "nO":
#            scorefile.write(namer+" = "+str(point)+" points" + "\n")
#            scorefile.close()
#        print(scf)
        #print("leaderboard:")
#        print("""       Thanks for playing
#        I hope you will play again soon!""")
    windowEA.after(100,update)
#-------------------------------------output------------------------------------

windowEA.after(10,update) windowEA.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific than "it crashes"? How does it crash? Do you get an error? If so, what is the error?

Comment: When I run the code and go through the login process I press the login button then it clears all as it should but then the tkinter canvas becomes not responsive so I have to close it.

Comment: It probably becomes unresponsive because you have an infinite loop. Have you added debugging statements to see what the code is doing? Once you enter the loop, it is impossible for `gay` to become `False`.

Comment: That might be the case I will check on Monday (next time I can) and thanks for the help